# "fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision" when using rebase after fetch

Tags: git

I am trying to fetch my remote repository and run this:

```
git fetch origin
```

then run this:

```
git rebase origin/main
```

but got an error:

```
$ git rebase origin/main
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
```

What does this mean? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try first a `git status`, to understand where you are in your local repository.

For instance, if you have just created an empty repository, and added origin, you could not rebase your current non-existent local branch on top of `origin/main`.

Check the output of `git branch -avv`.
If you have a branch main, try and switch back to it.

```
git switch main
```

Then, and only then, try a simple `git pull`.

Comment: I tried `git status` still the same error.

Comment: @Myrat a git status in a newly created repository would not indeed be able to resolve HEAD. What `git branch -avv` returns? (and what is your Git version? On which OS are you?)